# How to fix the gap between the 2 text boxes?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple reminder system, you post a title and some text and you get the reminder on your account page. The issue is, the boxes that the title and text are in are too far apart, I would have prefered them to have no gap in between them.

I am currently running this from file, I have tried messing around with some CSS but nothing has really worked.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssforsite.css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=#b8b6f2>
        <p>This is a test</p>
        <hr>
        <h2 style="background-color: #9693ed ; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(172, 117, 235);">Text</h2>
        <p style="background-color: #7b77ed ; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(131, 93, 238);">text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
.centre {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
  }


  h1 {color: lightblue}
  h2 {color: blue}

  a:link {
    color: lightblue;
    padding: 7.5px 21.5px; 
    background-color: blueviolet; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  a:visited {
    color: lightblue;
    padding: 7.5px 21.5px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: lightblue;
    background-color: purple;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  a:active {
    color: lightgreen;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  hr {
    border-color: purple;
    }

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
}
div.ignore-css{all:unset;}
```

I expected there to be a gap if I put br in but not if I left it blank.

Comment: Both `p` and `h2` have default margins.

Comment: I don't see any HTML tags that reference the CSS classes for "centre" or "right".  To use those CSS definitions, tags need 'class="centre" ', or 'class="right" ' embedded within them to use these CSS definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that html elements have certain default values for certain properties. For example, if we look at [this list from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), we can see that `<h2>` has the following default values:

```
h2  display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.83em;
    margin-bottom: 0.83em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
```

and `<p>` has the following:

```
p   display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
```

What you can do if you want to remove the default margins, is specifically set the `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` properties of your elements to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your h2 as below to remove white space between two elements-

h2 {color: blue; margin:0px !important;}

Any other element showing whitespace then it should be removed by setting margin as 0.